# SourceTree Switching branch has an error？

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Operating system is macos, every switch will report this error, but the switch has succeeded, how to deal with it?

```
fatal: No url found for submodule path test.cn/src/gitlab.com/go-box/pongo2gin' in .gitmodules
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

As in [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-says-No-url-found-for-submodule-path/qaq-p/628869), check first if you have any `.gitmodules`, whose content might be ill-formed (ie, declaring a path without an associated URL)

But if you do *not* have any `.gitmodules` file, then check for any file pretending to be one:

Example:

> ```
> git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
>
> 160000 b06580880c5eaf8b1564f74c30d595bc6a363a13 0 APPNAME
> ```
>
> I performed
>
> ```
> bash-3.2$ git rm --cached APPNAME and the error was fixed.
> ```